# Get a number from a class of a HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've got an element with multiple classes in a page and I need to dynamically get the number at the end of a specific class name.

Example:

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-555 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-thumbnail">
    ...
</div>
```

In particular I've to get "3" from `gallery-columns-3`.

I've made this function in Javascript/Jquery, but I think that there is a better solution.

```
//return the number of columns from gallery class
function get_gallery_columns($el){
    var class_arr = $el.attr('class').split(/\s+/).filter(function (el) {
        return el.includes("gallery-columns-");
    });

    if(class_arr.length < 1){
        return false;
    }

    return parseInt(class_arr[0].replace(/\D/g,''));
}
```

I wanted to do this to dynamically create the layout of Wordpress galleries.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//galleries selector
var $galleries = $('div[class*=gallery-columns-]');
fix_gallery($galleries);

//responsive gallery on resize
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    fix_gallery($galleries);
});

//fixes galleries size
function fix_gallery($galleries){
    $galleries.each(function(index) {
        var $current_gall = $(this);
        var n_cols = get_gallery_columns($current_gall);

        if(n_cols === false){
            return;
        }

        //if there are columns, unwrap images from them
        $current_gall.find(".gallery-group").replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents(); });

        //change columns on mobile/tablet
        if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 640px)").matches && n_cols > 2) {
            n_cols = 2;
        } else if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 800px)").matches && n_cols > 4) {
            n_cols = 4;
        } else if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 980px)").matches && n_cols > 6) {
            n_cols = 6;
        }

        //gallery pictures selector
        var $pictures = $current_gall.find('.gallery-item');
        //number of pictures
        var pic_number = $pictures.length;

        for (var i = 0;i <= pic_number; i += n_cols){
            $pictures.filter(':eq('+i+'),:lt('+(i+n_cols)+'):gt('+i+')').wrapAll('<div class="gallery-group" />');
        }

        $pictures.width((100/n_cols) + '%');

    });
}

//return the number of columns from gallery class
function get_gallery_columns($el){
    var class_arr = $el.attr('class').split(/\s+/).filter(function (el) {
        return el.includes("gallery-columns-");
    });

    if(class_arr.length < 1){
        return false;
    }

    return parseInt(class_arr[0].replace(/\D/g,''));
}

});
```

Comment: There are a couple of code smells here, are you sure you want to shorten it above all else?

Comment: Are you looking for a shorter solution, or just general improvement? (i.e. speed, memory, and cleaner code)  CR doesn't really do the first bit as far as I know, but [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) might be able to help.

Comment: Yes I'm looking for a faster code not only shorter

Comment: Could you provide more context? Why do you want to do this? There may be a better design that does not involve this kind of parsing.

Comment: I've built a script to create dynamically the columns of the wordpress default gallery in posts

Comment: **Shorter** code: [`Number(el.attr('class').match(/\bgallery-columns-(\d+)(?:\b|$)/)[1] || DEFAULT_COLUMNS);`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/cyuz4dm0/)

Comment: I would recommend storing the number on a data attribute, something like: `<div data-column='3' ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just

```
const getGalleryColumns = element => element.className.match(/\bgallery-columns-(\d+)\b/)[1];
```

```js
const getGalleryColumns = element => element.className.match(/\bgallery-columns-(\d+)\b/)[1];

console.log(getGalleryColumns(document.getElementById('gallery-1')));
```

```css
/* Output console formatting */
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-555 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-thumbnail">...</div>
```

In the above code you just take all classes of given element and you match your number using regex. Simple, fast, concise.

It is more efficient, because there is no splitting and filtering involved.

Same code in previous specification of JS:

```
function getGalleryColumns(element) {
  return element.className.match(/\bgallery-columns-(\d+)\b/)[1];
}
```

<sub>EDIT due to comment: It should be noted that this function will return error if called on element without matching class. If this function is going to be used on such elements, it would be wise to modify it by enclosing the entire match (everything between `return` and `[1]`) by the following code: `(MATCH_HERE || true)`.</sub>

Comment: Yeah sorry @cFreed but that solution is much efficient. Thanks to both.

Comment: @ClaudioKing I admit this solution presents a pretty good improvement, by simply integrating the regex instead of previously splitting the `class` attribute. In the other hand, warning: it doesn't match the OP's requirement and fires an error rather returning `false` when the given `element` has no class like `gallery-columns-...`. In addition, it uses ES6 syntax so it'll not work with IE (only Edge accepts it).

Comment: @cFreed: Hey, other than use of `false` in OP's code I didn't found any mention of requirement on returning it. But it's a fact, that the error is not what this function should return. This problem can be solved by enclosing `match()` in `(CODE || true)`. I have edited my answer to include this remark. Regarding ES6, I have provided non-ES6 solution at the bottom of my answer and even if I wouldn't do it, transpiler such as Babel can be used. Thanks for keeping open-eyes, anyway :).

Comment: @Przemek You're right: there was not really a "requirement" in the OP. But reading it I considered it was an implicit one. In the other hand, sorry: I didn't notice you already mentioned a non-ES6 version.

Answer (score 1):

You might use something like the snippet below, that is:

- sure a bit shorter
- probably faster, because:

  1. using `find()` rather than `filter()` makes the loop stop as soon as the desired result is got
  2. looking for the involved class-prefix and extracting the number are both processed in the same statement
- and browser agnostic, while `includes()` is not recognized by IE

```js
function get_gallery_columns($el) {
  var matches, result = false;
  $el.attr('class').split(/\s+/).find(function (className) {
    if (matches = className.match(/^gallery-columns-(\d+)$/)) {
      result = +matches[1];
      return true;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(get_gallery_columns($('#gallery-1')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-555 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-thumbnail">
    ...
</div>
```